# Import data from three xls files into three sheets

Tags: excel, vba

I want to import data from three .xls files into three worksheets.

I have a userform with following script:

```vb
Private Sub Button_SelectFile_Click()
    
    SelectedFile = Application.GetOpenFilename(fileFilter:="Excel-Dateien (*.xls; *.xlsm; *.xlsx),*.xls; *.xlsm; *.xlsx", Title:="Bitte SAP-Export-Datei auswählen", MultiSelect:=True)
    
    If VarType(SelectedFile) = vbBoolean Then
        If SelectedFile = False Then
            Auswertung.Label_SelectedFile.Caption = "Ausgewählte Dateien: Keine"
            Exit Sub
        End If
    Else
        Auswertung.Label_SelectedFile.Caption = "Ausgewählte Dateien: " & Join(SelectedFile, "; ")
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub Button_Start_Click()
     
    Dim Box
    
    If VarType(SelectedFile) = vbEmpty Then
        Box = MsgBox("Bitte wählen Sie mindestens eine Datei aus.", vbOKOnly, "Keine Datei ausgewählt")
        If Box = vbOK Then
            Exit Sub
        End If

    Else
        Box = MsgBox("Möchten Sie das Programm starten?", vbOKCancel)
        If Box = vbOK Then
            'Starten'
            Call Generate_Database(SelectedFile)
        Else
            Exit Sub
        End If
    End If
    
End Sub
```

I want to use the Sub "Generate_Database(SelectedFile)" to get the data from the three files into the three sheets.

Comment: I suppose that `SelectedFile` variable is declared (`As Variant`) on top of the form code module (in the declarations area). Is that true? If yes, "import the data from 3 different .xls files into 3 specific Worksheets" is not enough to create the necessary `Sub` you are asking for.  What if you select only two such files, or 5? Do each workbooks in discussion have only one sheet? If not, which sheet to be copied? Do you need to also copy the sheet format?

Comment: Should the supposed 'DataBase' be a new workbook? If yes, should it be saved somewhere? If yes, where? What does "3 specific Worksheets" means? Should they receive a specific name? If yes, where from to be taken?

Comment: Hi, thank you for your response. Yes I used `Option Explicit
Public SelectedFile As Variant`. Each Workbook has only one sheet. The Workbooks name is matching with the name of the Sheet. I want to select only 3 or less. Example the data from Workbook1 should go into the existing sheet Workbook1 and so on. The format is irrelevant to me. I hope that makes it a little clearer.

Comment: You did not answer the clarification question related to the workbook where the three sheets to be copied... Should it be created? Shouldn't it be saved? If more than 3 such workbooks will be selected, what to be done? Should the code copy only from the first three of them? Should it worn about the number limit exceeding 3? Or, what?

Comment: The three sheets from the three workbooks should get copied into three already existing sheets. If more then 3 Workbooks are selected then the system should give out an error message like `Box = MsgBox("You can only select 3 Workbooks", vbOKCancel)` and not start at all.

Comment: You only implicitly answered my question... So, not a new workbook will be created. Will they be copied in the workbook keeping the code? If existing, in which of them to paste the sheets in discussion? How the code to know that? You must understand that we are not mind readers and, in order to receive help, you must make us understand exactly what is to be done...

Comment: Still alive? Do you need help? I must leave my office in about an hour. If I will be able to understand what you want, I can try preparing an answer. But it is not convenient to ask for clarification and not receive any answer... I will also like to emphasize that, even if I will leave my office, somebody else wanting to help will not be able to do it without clearly knowing what you really need...

Comment: Sorry, I am trying to be more specific. So I have on Master .xlm in which is the code. With my Userform I want to import the data from three or less Workbooks which contain each one sheet. The data should go into three already existing sheets in my master xlm. The names of the Workbooks which i want to import the data from have the same names as the already existing sheets in my master xlm. Does this make more sense to you?

Comment: Master xlm.  includes Worksheets "Sample1", "Sample2", "Sample3" 
Workbooks i want to import - Sample1.xls, Sample2.xls, Sample3.xls 
Data from Sample1.xls should go into Sheet "Sample1", Data from Sample2.xls into Sheet "Sample2" etc.

Comment: Is the single sheet of workbook "Sample1.xls" named as "Sample1"?

Comment: Unfortunately no the single sheets have the standard names (In Germany it's "Tabelle1"). But if it is a requirement it would be possible to name them too.

Comment: It is not any requirement! What do you understand reading "**The names of the Workbooks which i want to import the data from have the same names as the already existing sheets in my master xlm**"? Isn't it what you stated? Do you want meaning that for a  "Sample1.xls" workbook, there is a sheet named Sample1, but the sheet to be copied does not have this name? I already made a piece of code, according to my understanding, but I cannot finish it without knowing the real situation...

Comment: I mean by that - the **Sample1.xls** has the same name as the sheet **"Sample1"** in my master .xlm.  The Sheet name from the Sample1.xls is just the basic one when you create an excel.

Comment: OK. I will try making it in this way...

Comment: Please, try the code I posted and send some feedback.

Comment: `Application.GetOpenFilename` will let you choose the files. How have you made sure that only some or all of the mentioned files (`S1.xls,S2.xls,S3.xls`) will be selected? Or do you mean any random file's first worksheet will be copied? Please clarify.

Comment: @VBasic2008 I think the answer at your question is yes... At least, this is what I understood and posted an answer. Anyhow, if the user selects something unappropriated and no sheet with the name of the workbook will be found, the code will warn about it and stop working...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please, try the next code:

```
Sub Generate_Database(arrWb As Variant)
   Dim El, wb As Workbook, wbCopy As Workbook
   Dim shP As Worksheet, shName As String, arrC
   
   If Not IsArray(arrWb) Then Exit Sub
   If UBound(arrWb) > 3 Then MsgBox _
          "Too many workbooks selected (" & UBound(arrWb) + 1 & ") instead of maximum 3...": Exit Sub
   Set wb = ThisWorkbook

   For Each El In arrWb
        Set wbCopy = Workbooks.Open(El)
        shName = Split(Right(El, Len(El) - InStrRev(El, "\")), ".")(0) 'extract the sheet name from wb name
        arrC = wbCopy.Sheets(1).UsedRange.Value
        On Error Resume Next
         Set shP = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(shName)
         If err Then
            err.Clear: On Error GoTo 0
            MsgBox "Not possible to find the sheet named " & shName & "...": Exit Sub
         End If
        On Error GoTo 0
        With shP.Range("A1").Resize(UBound(arrC), UBound(arrC, 2))
                .Value = arrC
                .EntireColumn.AutoFit
        End With
        wbCopy.Close False
   Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks you so much. Sorry for my bad explaining skills. I am trying to do it better from the beginning the next time i need some help. This is exactly how i wanted it to be.

Comment: @Nelina Glad I (finally) could help! It is good to understand that the way you describe the problem in your question is essential to let us know what you really need. Even as a programmer (not my case), it is mandatory to have a plan based on what to develop a piece of code. Without the required clarifications, I do not think that somebody wanting to help could do too much...